# In JavaScript, is formatting a date for user display with Intl.DateTimeFormat not best practice?

Tags: javascript, date, format

When I look up how to display a date for users in a short month, day, full year format (like "Mar 24, 2015"), I always get answers about using splice methods to format it. But I was taught that the correct way to do it would be to use the Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor -- for example:

```
const displayFormSubmissionDate =  Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", {year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "numeric"}).format(new Date(formSubmissionDate));
```

Is this no longer best practice? If not, why not?

Since "best practice" tends to go in and out of fashion depending on current standards, but the results from Google searches tend to favor whatever has been around the longest, I can't figure out if the splice approach to formatting dates is the current best practice or if it just pre-dates the Intl.DateTimeFormat() so it's weighted as the de-facto results.

Comment: "Best" can only be determined by comparison with your criteria or requirements. *toLocaleString* may not produce consistent results across implementations and is subject to change based on whatever the CLDR says the format should be. It may be appropriate in cases where those things don't matter.